# Can't install Imagick for PHP on Debian from source, error says requires 6.2.4 when I have 6.7.7 installed

Tags: php, pecl, imagemagick

Pulling my hair out.  PHP built from source, everything working.  Now need to install imagick and can't get it installed.

I am running Debian on kernel 3.7.1 with PHP 5.3.20 (the last version my app supports, cannot go to PHP 5.4).

```
pecl install imagick
...
checking ImageMagick MagickWand API configuration program... found in /usr/bin/Wand-config
checking if ImageMagick version is at least 6.2.4... configure: error: no. You need at least Imagemagick version 6.2.4 to use Imagick.
ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/configure --with-imagick' failed
```

Yet, I have version 6.7.7 installed:

```
# convert --version
Version: ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2012-11-06 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2012 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP
```

I also tried installing the latest beta (pecl install imagick-beta), same result.  Also tried an old version 2.3.0, same result.  Also tried downloading source, phpize, and configure -- same result.

Comment: What returns `MagickWand-config --version` command?

Comment: Another guess: in Debian, binary `MagickWand-config` is a part of `libmagickwand-dev` package. Is this package installed in your system?

Answer (score 5):

I was finally able to solve this myself.  I ended up doing:

```
apt-get remove graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat imagemagick imagemagick-common
apt-get autoremove
```

Then:

```
apt-get install libmagickwand-dev
```

And finally was able to get imagick installed via pecl without error:

```
pecl install imagick-beta
```

Answer (score 1):

Best solution to solve this problem is installing Imagemagick-Devel package.

In RHEL based OSes you can run this command:

```
yum install ImageMagick-devel
```

For Debian systems:

```
sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev imagemagick libmagickcore-dev
```